# Proxy requests to virtual host in by path prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, torquebox

I'm running multiple Rails applications on TorqueBox. Each application is mounted on a different web context, e.g., `localhost:8080/app1` and `localhost:8080/app2` (configured via TorqueBox). Apache is configured to accept requests to `app1.domain.com` and `app2.domain.com` via virtual hosts. However, I'm running into problems where some application paths (form submission paths and others) expect to be preceeded by `/app1`, e.g., `http://app1.domain.com/app1/rest/of/path` instead of the correct `http://app1.domain.com/rest/of/path`.

How can I configure Apache so that the requests to `http://app1.domain.com/app1/...` are made to the correct path (i.e., without the leading `/app1`)? I've tried doing this with redirects but that doesn't work since they force a GET request and the POST data is lost in the process.

This is my current Apache config:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>  # There are multiple vhosts like this one, for different apps.
    ServerName app1.domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/app1/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/app1/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I got the same problem but with nginx. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Try setting the host instead of the context in the TorqueBox configuaration. For example, instead of using context '/sub1', use host 'sub1.domain.tld'. Then everything should work fine. See this: http://torquebox.org/documentation/3.0.1/deployment-descriptors.html#ruby-descriptor-layout

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Now I'm stuck within the nginx configuration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by using a web host instead of a web context in the TorqueBox configuration. After that, getting the Apache configuration to work was no problem since different apps were not under specific context paths.

So, instead of this (in `config/torquebox.rb`):

```
TorqueBox.configure do
  web do
    context '/app1' 
  end
end
```

You should do this:

```
TorqueBox.configure do
  web do
    host 'app1.domain.tld'
  end
end
```

Comment: On TorqueBox 3.1 I'm having seemingly [the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292781/proxy-requests-to-virtual-host-in-by-path-prefix), and even have the same config, but unfortunately in my case I have found no working solution.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Got it clarified and [put a more detailed response in my thread as noted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24245931/320681).