# Duplication of context in path for a Rails app on TorqueBox with Apache ReverseProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, torquebox

I am struggling with a scenario where I have several applications to run on a singular TorqueBox instance.  When defining an app and deploying it to a root ("/") context within `config/torquebox.yml` the application executes properly with no apparent problems.  At first I believed that this was a problem with Apache reverse proxy, but now believe it is likely an issue with Rails and/or TorqueBox, yet I can't find a clear answer or reason for the issue.

This configuration is as follows:

`config/torquebox.yml` contains:

```
web:
  context: /
```

Apache's httpd virtual host config for proxy is:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

With this I can visit `http://sub.domain.tld/`, with `posts` and `posts/new` routes just fine.  This is by roughly following [the example here](http://torquebox.org/getting-started/current/first-steps.html#first-steps-full-distro)  (only modifications I've performed are the ones to get reverse proxy working).

But when I switch gears and run it with a context of `torquebox_test_rails_production` things start to get really strange.  I am left to believe that there is something wrong where rails will append a duplicate copy of the context onto the path for some reason.  To explain:

I change `config/torquebox.yml` to:

```
web:
  context: /torquebox_test_rails_production
```

and Apache's httpd virtual host conf to:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/torquebox_test_rails_production/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/torquebox_test_rails_production/
```

When I do this, `http://sub.domain.tld/` still loads okay, but then when I go to `posts`, I notice (in `log/production.log`) a failed GET request:

```
INFO -- : Started GET "/torquebox_test_rails_production/torquebox_test_rails_production/stylesheets/application.css"
FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/torquebox_test_rails_production/stylesheets/application.css"):
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
```

As you can note, it duplicates the context there on the path.

At this point the URL is still correct with simply `http://sub.domain.tld/posts`, but then when I click "New Post" in the scaffolded test, the app then attempts to redirect the browser to   `http://sub.domain.tld/torquebox_test_rails_production/posts/new`.  Obviously this redirection / duplication should not be occurring.  Within the log I now see:

```
INFO -- : Started GET "/torquebox_test_rails_production/torquebox_test_rails_production/posts/new"
FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/torquebox_test_rails_production/posts/new"):
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
```

One other thing that I attempted here was to add `config.relative_url_root` to the config.  I did this via both trying the env variable of:

```
RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT="/torquebox_test_rails_production"
```

and setting it in `config/environments/production.rb` to:

```
config.relative_url_root = "/torquebox_test_rails_production"
```

I would assume that this should be set itself via the context setting and therefore its purpose, but I thought it was worth a try.

I also took a cue from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292781/proxy-requests-to-virtual-host-in-by-path-prefix) which seemed to be identical to mine, but eliminating `context` from `torquebox.yml` and just having the hostname did not solve the issue either.  Instead, it seems to have eliminated the doubling of the context to path, BUT I end up with still the following error in `log/production.log`:

```
INFO -- : Started GET "/torquebox_test_rails_production/posts"
FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/torquebox_test_rails_production/posts"):
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
```

I then also attempted to define `config.relative_url_root` in `production.rb` as noted earlier with precisely the same result as just noted in terms of the error.

Any idea as to what may be happening here to provoke this behavior?

Comment: Don't use Apache for proxies -- try Nginx instead. It was created for this reason, and performs better than Apache. See here: http://serverfault.com/questions/143238/nginx-vs-apache-as-reverse-proxy-which-one-to-choose

Comment: @DamienRoche Nginx is not an option for this situation, but thanks for the suggestion.  I would certainly be using it if it were an option.  Additionally this is using httpd 2.4 so it's effectively on par with nginx now at any rate.

Comment: That's a shame. Good luck finding a solution, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was that I needed to use root context ("/") with the host definition and then to remove the context out of the mod_proxy configuration.

Therefore, in the end, what worked was the following in `config/torquebox.yml`:

```
web:
  context: /
  host: sub.domain.tld
```

And the following in the httpd mod_proxy section for the virtual host:

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an Apache config handy to test but is it that you have a trailing slash in your ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse but not in your web context in your torquebox.yml?

So instead of

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/torquebox_test_rails_production/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/torquebox_test_rails_production/
```

try

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/torquebox_test_rails_production
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/torquebox_test_rails_production
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding a trailing "/" to the context of `config/torquebox.yml` still has identical behavior.  When I *remove* the postfix "/" from the proxypas url arg I end up getting apache immediately adding the context to the url and a 404 in my access logs for this site.  As per some direction from `thumbs` in IRC yesterday, the trailing "/" should essentially always be used for httpd reverse proxy pass conf.